# Various UI patterns for connecting panoramic images in a virtual tour

Tags: usability, input, maps, graphs, photos

Here is the problem:

There is a number of panoramic images available, made mostly in the indoor environment. Our user is assembling them all into a virtual tour, where a different kind of user will be traveling from one image to another by clicking on some sort of hotspot in a panoramic image (e.g. like Street View in Google Maps, but much smaller scale).

So, one way or another, our user will need to create connections between panoramas, with each connection also creating two hotspots - one for each image. Because the environment is indoors, the only images/locations to be connected are those where it's possible to physically go from one location to the other (and back - assume all connections are two-sided).

Unfortunately, no coordinates where the images were taken are available for images. We can assume that most of the images/locations are taken on more or less the same height level, so only the horizontal positioning matters. Orientation data, however, may or may not be available - we are still looking into it.

The question is: **how to implement the UI and workflow for our user so they can create those connections easily and efficiently?**

At this point, only the basic suggestions are needed. Is it possible to avoid creating every connection manually? Is it necessary to make the user create a map of sorts? Has this been done before and are there good examples?

Comment: For manual building (easily and efficiently), I think you need graph building tool, where nodes are pamoramas, and edges create connections. The task is to align entry points then to keep smooth journey. If you will not find  automation tools, please let me know, I have a sketch for manual mode.

Comment: Hi Septagram, is this question still relevant/open? Sounds to me like such a project wouldn't wait for six months to be picked up. If it is still relevant, i might give it a shot.

Comment: @GinovandeStaaij Thanks, but no, it isn't: we never reached an agreement with a client on it. Still, if you have some ideas you can put into words, it may end up being helpful for someone else solving the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 1):

While a "Click a doorway, enter the room" UI is certainly a viable approach, i would argue that people looking to tour a house don't really want to have first *click the stairs to see the master bedroom*.

Perhaps try something along the lines of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbLbV.jpg), where the background is the panorama, and the circles in the foreground are links to different rooms around the house.

So long as the links are visually identifiable as a master bedroom, a bathroom, a living room and so on, people will have no difficulty navigating the house. You may also want to consider strategically placing the more visually impressive rooms on the left of the list, so they get seen first.

Answer (score 0):

There is similar implementation in commonfloor.com, a real estate website.

https://www.commonfloor.com/listing/4bhk-house-for-sale-in-k-r-puram-bangalore/55a86ca3f41a6

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but the screenshot above demonstrates viewing a 3D tour. The question is about the UI for creating the tour.